# Rails 3 - How to escape flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-escape

Should the flash message be escaped automatically by Rails? If not, how to ensure message gets escaped (without using `CGI::escapeHTML`)?

After doing some searching, I figured out that it should be escaped, and one got to html_safe a message to display html. But when I try

```
flash[:error] = "<b>YO</b>"
```

it is displayed as bold **YO** and not as `<b>YO</b>`. Note that string object is not html_safe itself.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to handle this is in the final place you display your flash message, which is most likely to be `application.html.erb`. change

```
<%= message %>
```

in

```
  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>
```

to

```
<%= sanitize message %>
```

remember always apply `sanitize` to the string at the end point of the pipeline your string goes through to ensure you get your style.

Answer (score 0):

the questions stated without using `CGI::escapeHTML`. You can use a `ERB::Util.html_escape` in the controller

```
flash[:error] = escape_html('<b>Yo</b>')
....

private
  def escape_html(string_to_escape)
    ERB::Util.html_escape(string_to_escape)
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `html_safe` in your controller for flash message that you want escaped. It remove the raw function from the view.

```
flash[:error] = "<b>YO</b>".html_safe
```

Comment: Making it 'html_safe' actually prevents the string from being escaped at all.